# Meaning of the following template function?

Tags: c++, template-function, explicit-instantiation

```
#define Create_Function(Type) \
    template void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Type>>&)

Create_Function(std::string);
```

I have seen the above code in legacy code but have no idea what the meaning of it. It is neither a regular non-specialized function definition nor a full specialized function definition.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does **explicit template instantiation** (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

> Explicit instantiation lets you create an instantiation of a templated
>   class or function without actually using it in your code. Because this
>   is useful when you are creating library (.lib) files that use
>   templates for distribution, uninstantiated template definitions are
>   not put into object (.obj) files.

Given a general function template

```
template<typename T>
void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T>>&)
{
    // bla bla
}
```

The call to the macro `Create_Function(std::string);` will expand to

```
template void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<std::string>>&);
```

Comment: my question is that what is the syntax of your last line? I only know the following two 1> `template<typename T>` or `template<class T>` 2> `template<> void Function`. Why you can just simply put a template in front of the function name?

Comment: @q0987 The statement will instruct the compiler to instantiate the function template for `std::string`. This means that code is generated for that particular instance of the template.

Comment: @q0987 As explained by David R., the uses for this syntax are quite advanced (optimizing for object size, compile times etc.). But sometimes you really need it (e.g. when you write header-only libraries).

Comment: @rhalbersam, does it conflict with the idea posted here "http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm" Why Not Specialize Function Templates?

Comment: @q0987 No, you simply tell the compiler that you will be using the function template with `std::string` as template argument. YOu don't make an explicit specialization for `std::string` (in the sense that you have a separate implementation for `std::string`).

Comment: @q0987: You are not providing different behavior for different specializations of the function, you are only requiring the compiler to generate the code *here* instead of on demand on each and every translation unit that requires it (reducing compilation times, limiting the types that can be used as template arguments, and allowing for the template code not to be delivered as part of the headers --as the generated code can be linked in a library).

Answer (score 3):

That is an explicit instantiation of a function template. Given a template like:

```
template <typename T>
void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T> >& );
```

(probably declared in a header and defined in a .cpp file), the code:

```
template void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<int> >& );
```

requires that the compiler *instantiates* (generates code for) the specialization in this translation unit. This can be used to reduce compile times, as users of the template would only need to see the declaration of the template and won't instantiate it in each translation unit where it is used. On the down side, it requires that for each type used with that template, the explicit instantiation is performed in a translation unit that has access to the definition of the template, which limits the use of the template to those instantiations.

```
// tmpl.h
template <typename T>
void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T> >& );

// tmpl.cpp
template <typename T>
void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T> >& p ) {
    ... 
}
template void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<int> >& );
template void Function( std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<double> >& );

// user.cpp, user2.cpp, user3.cpp
#include <tmpl.h>
...
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<int> > v;
    Function( v );                             // [1]
```

In this example, when compiling 'user#.cpp' we don't incur the cost of instantiation of the `Function` template in *all* translation units that *odr-use* it, only in 'tmpl.cpp', potentially reducing the compilation time.

Sometimes the *down* side is actually the reason for this approach, as you can effectively limit the instantiating types to the subset for which you have provided the explicit instantiation (i.e. in the code above, if 'userN.cpp' tried to call `Function` passing a vector of shared pointers to `std::string` the linker will complain).

Finally, in a few cases I have seen it as a way of hiding the actual implementation of the template from users of a library *when* the set of types for which it can be used is limited.

Comment: @rhalbersma: You beat me with your edit while I was writing the *elaborate exmplanation*. :)

Comment: Yeah that happens to me all the time. Initial sentence submitters who then rapidly expand the answer. At least there are captcha solvers to deal with the rapid-firers ;-)

Comment: @rhalbersma: Are there? I have only got captcha when I was too slow and the page had forgotten that I was editing.

Comment: I guess it's reputation dependent. I'm not over 10K, so .. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing?lq=1